# Php 2d array as C# 2d array/struct

Tags: c#, php, arrays, struct

I'm using MailChimp's API to subscribe email to a list. Function [listsubscribe()](http://www.mailchimp.com/api/1.2/listsubscribe.func.php) is used for email subscription:

```
public static  listSubscribe(string apikey, string id, string email_address, array merge_vars, string email_type, boolean double_optin, boolean update_existing, boolean replace_interests, boolean send_welcome)
```

I downloaded MailChimp's official [.NET wrapper](http://www.mailchimp.com/api/downloads/) for their API

When looking in Visual Studio, this is one of overloaded functions:

```
listSubscribe(string apikey, string id, string email_address, MCMergeVar[] merges)
```

When I click on definition of MCMergeVar[], this comes out:

```
[XmlRpcMissingMapping(MappingAction.Ignore)]
    public struct MCMergeVar
    {
        public string name;
        public bool req;
        [XmlRpcMissingMapping(MappingAction.Error)]
        public string tag;
        public string val;
    }
```

In a php example on MailChimp's website, this is how `merges` variable is declared:

```
$merge_vars = array('FNAME'=>'Test', 'LNAME'=>'Account', 'INTERESTS'=>'');
```

How to write this array correctly for my C# wrapper?
I tried something like this:

```
MCMergeVar[] subMergeVars = new MCMergeVar[1];
subMergeVars["FNAME"] = "Test User";
```

But it requires an `int` in place where `"FNAME"` is now placed, so this doesn't work...

Thanks in advance,
Ile

**EDIT 1:**
I tried FoxFire's solution but no data from subMergeVars is passed to MailChimp server, only email is passed:

```
// Subscribe email to list
            string subID = "26973e52cc";
            string subEmail = "mymail@some.com.hr";
            MCMergeVar[] subMergeVars = new MCMergeVar[5];
            subMergeVars[0].name = "FNAME";
            subMergeVars[0].val = "FNDynamic";
            subMergeVars[1].name = "LNAME";
            subMergeVars[1].val = "LNDynamic";

            mailChimp.api.listSubscribe(subID, subEmail, subMergeVars, "html");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely:

```
MCMergeVar[] subMergeVars = new MCMergeVar[1]; 
subMergeVars[0].name = "FNAME"; 
subMergeVars[0].val = "Test User";
```

Comment: It looks ok to me, but data is still not passed to MailChimp server... I will now edit my question with example I tried

Comment: I figured it out... .name needs to be replaced with .val and it works just fine :)
Thanks!

Comment: Its not clear what you mean by ".name needs to be replaced with .val".
Could you post a snippet?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't write correctly, it was suppose to be ".name needs to be replaced with .tag", like this `subMergeVars[0].tag = "FNAME";` instead of `subMergeVars[0].name = "FNAME";`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
var mergeVars = new List<MCMergeVar>();

mergeVars.Add(new MCMergeVar() { tag = "FNAME", val = "Test User First Name" });
mergeVars.Add(new MCMergeVar() { tag = "LNAME", val = "Test User Last Name" });
```

Then use:

```
mergeVars.ToArray()
```